# SELECT only values defined in INFORMATION SCHEMA

Tags: sql, t-sql, information-schema

Could you please help me with following issue?

Source table:

[image]

Columns defined from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS:

[image]

In output I'd like to take my source table, but show only values which column name is the same as column name defined in information schema. Meaning:

[image]

Is it possible? Many thanks in advance

Comment: When you start wanting to mix metadata querying and data querying in a single query, it's usually a sign that the data model is wrong. E.g. here it looks like the source table should be something like `ID,Year,Month,WhateverValue` and rows should be like `1,2019,12,15` and `2,2020,1,6`. And then it should just go back to being a straightforward data query.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use dynamic SQL to do that:

```
declare @sql varchar(1000) 'select ';
select @sql = @sql + '[' + column_name + '] ,' from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;
-- remove last character in a string which is comma
select @sql = left(@sql, len(@sql) - 1);
-- you need to change talbe name here
select @sql = @sql + ' from MyTable';
-- execute statement
exec(@sql)
```

Comment: Thanks Michal. One additional question, if I may. I get an error for this line: sql = sql + ' from MyTable';. What exactly is expected here? FROM sourcetablename?

Comment: @JurajC Updated answer. If it helped you you should accept it (green check mark on the left) and optionally upvote.